# Calling AbortController.abort() on resolved fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a React app that can makes a series of fetch requests, depending on user interactions.  I want to abort old fetch requests any time the app receives a new one.

To accomplish this, I've created a custom hook, `useData`. Its main fucntion is running a `useEffect` hook whenever the `url` changes. The easiest way to abort old requests seems to me to be using the [cleanup mechanism](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) provided by `useEffect`. But this will call `abort` on all requests, not just incomplete ones.

Are there any hidden problems this might cause? It seems that it shouldn't do much to a resolved fetch, but I can't find any documentation to support that.

This is my code:

```js
/** Returns data for a given url. */
export const useData = function (dataUrl) {
  const [loadedData, setLoadedData] = useState(Object.assign({}));

  // runs if/when the url changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // new controller for each new url
    const controller = new AbortController();
    
    async function getData(dataUrl) {
      if (!dataUrl) return;

      // load data & set state
      try {
        const data = await fetch(dataUrl, {
          signal: controller.signal,
        });
        setLoadedData(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(`useData failed for url ${dataUrl}\n${e}.`);
      }
    }

    getData(dataUrl);

    // clean up the last request before running 
    // useEffect for on the next url
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };

  }, [dataUrl]);

  // return data in the hook's state, set by useEffect
  return loadedData;
};
```

Comment: What do you call "a resolved fetch"? Is it just really about the Promise returned by `fetch()` or is it about the whole request? The `fetch()` Promise will be resolved before the full response body has been fetched, the request can thus still be aborted at that time, and if you never did consume the response's body, even after it's been completely fetched, triggering the controller would still make the consumer throw.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise so, once it resolves, any abortion does not have any effects.

You can run this simple demo in the console, you'll see that the request completes (at least until connection) and no errors are generated:

```js
async function test() {
  const controller = new AbortController()
  const request = await fetch('https://stackoverflow.com', {signal: controller.signal})
  console.log('The request was ok?', request.ok)
  controller.abort();
}

test();
```